# Pass ID from one html element to another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

my problem is pretty simple. I'm trying to switch 2 elements id by clicking either of them using only vanilla JavaScript.

It works on the first click to use the correct CSS for the new id, but afterward, it does not seem to recognize click events to the new id. Here is a short code example to illustrate this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var blueSpin = document.getElementById("blue-spinner");
    var orangeSpin = document.getElementById("orange-spinner");
    blueSpin.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "You've Clicked Blue";
        blueSpin.setAttribute("id","orange-spinner");
        orangeSpin.setAttribute("id", "blue-spinner")
    });
    orangeSpin.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "You've Clicked Orange";
        orangeSpin.setAttribute("id", "blue-spinner");
        blueSpin.setAttribute("id", "orange-spinner");
    });
});
```

```css
h1, h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
 margin: 15px;
}
#blue-spinner {
 color: blue;
}
#orange-spinner {
 color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 id="h1">Click Something:</h1>
        <h2 id="blue-spinner"><i class="fa fa-cubes fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
        <h2 id="orange-spinner"><i class="fa fa-cubes fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that upon clicking either spinner, the colors will switch, and the header will identify which one was clicked before the change. After that, you should be able to click either of the spinners with the same result.

Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated! Happy X-mas Eve Eve!

Comment: You've switched the IDs, but the click event listeners still reference the original elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use class selectors in css instead of id. Something along these lines:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var clss = e.target.getAttribute("class")
        if(clss === undefined || cls === null){clss = "";}
        if(cls.indexOf("blue-spinner") > -1){
            var output = "You clicked a blue spinner";
            e.target.setAttribute("class", "orange-spinner");
        }else{
            e.target.setAttribute("class", "blue-spinner");
            var output = "You clicked an orange spinner";
        }
        var h = document.getElementById("h1");
        h.innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you change the id for the element you have to update your code after the change.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var blueSpin = document.getElementById("blue-spinner");
    var orangeSpin = document.getElementById("orange-spinner");

    var blueSpinClick = function() {
      document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "You've Clicked Blue";
      blueSpin.removeEventListener('click', blueSpinClick);
      orangeSpin.removeEventListener('click', orangeSpinClick);
      blueSpin.removeEventListener('click', blueSpinClick);

      blueSpin.setAttribute("id","orange-spinner");
      orangeSpin.setAttribute("id", "blue-spinner");

      blueSpin = document.getElementById("blue-spinner");
      orangeSpin = document.getElementById("orange-spinner");

      blueSpin.addEventListener("click", blueSpinClick);
      orangeSpin.addEventListener("click", orangeSpinClick);
    }
    document.getElementById("blue-spinner").addEventListener("click", blueSpinClick);

    var orangeSpinClick = function() {
      document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = "You've Clicked Orange";
      orangeSpin.removeEventListener('click', orangeSpinClick);
      blueSpin.removeEventListener('click', blueSpinClick);

      blueSpin.setAttribute("id","orange-spinner");
      orangeSpin.setAttribute("id", "blue-spinner");

      blueSpin = document.getElementById("blue-spinner");
      orangeSpin = document.getElementById("orange-spinner");

      blueSpin.addEventListener("click", blueSpinClick);
      orangeSpin.addEventListener("click", orangeSpinClick);
    }
    document.getElementById("orange-spinner").addEventListener("click", orangeSpinClick);
});
```

```css
h1, h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
 margin: 15px;
}
#blue-spinner {
 color: blue;
}
#orange-spinner {
 color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/js/all.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
  <h1 id="h1">Click Something:</h1>
  <h2 id="blue-spinner"><i class="fa fa-cubes fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
  <h2 id="orange-spinner"><i class="fa fa-cubes fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be allowing the colors to switch properly, but what would I need to add in order for the header to correctly describe which of the colors was clicked?

Comment: I'm thinking about it... I think you should have a function that adds the event listener and then removes it and then adds it  again. This is interesting.

Comment: I'm sure you can get the same effect in a less convoluted way. You should not switch an element's `id`.

Comment: I thought about that. Is there another effective way to grab an element with vanilla js than by using its id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161886/discussion-between-sebastien-and-jason-leo).